Internal Server Error in Odoo (Windows 11)
I just installed Odoo in my Windows 11. But I'm getting an Internal server error. I tried looking for a solution to this online but I only found solutions for Linux. I also tried restarting the Odoo and postgres services but it's still not working. Can someone help?


I actually resolved it myself.
For anyone looking in the future, go to Run->Services and find the Odoo service. Then click on properties and in the Log On tab, change "This account" to "Local System Account".
